# What is the correct queryselector syntax to use with scrollToElement for iscroll?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-selectors, iscroll, iscroll4

I am using iscroll 4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) which uses document.queryselector to navigate links.

Syntactically, this works:

```
<a href="javascript:myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(50)'))">
```

but this doesn't:

```
<a href="javascript:myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#customid'))">
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#customid')` should just work. Did you try `document.getElementById('customid')` instead?

Comment: Unless you've got other js event targeting #customid, I would say your seletor is wrong. I used your code from line 2, and an ID selector form my iscroll project...worked just fine. Keep in mind, your selectors must be inside of the #scroller container to work

Comment: @Dawson, thanks - the link is outside the #scroller id but the target is inside it. Should this make a difference? I am going to set up a jsfiddle

Comment: You can use CSS selector of the DOM object. You can use '#customid' or '.your-class' or 'span p.your-class' etc.